# Looking for an efficient way to build some kind of "FIFO" table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I need to store measured data on a daily basis for a given period in the future, lets say 7 days. The current day should be always day 1.
Basic Example:

```
| id | day    | value |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 1      | 10    |
| 2  | 2      | 20    |        
| 3  | 3      | 30    |
| 4  | 4      | 40    |
| 5  | 5      | 50    |
| 6  | 6      | 60    |
| 7  | 7      | 70    |
```

So at night the next day (day 2) becomes day one and all data will move up one day, and new data can be added.

Basic Example:

```
| id | day    | value |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 1      | 20    |
| 2  | 2      | 30    |        
| 3  | 3      | 40    |
| 4  | 4      | 50    |
| 5  | 5      | 60    |
| 6  | 6      | 70    |
| 7  | 7      | 80    |
```

So the principle is kind of FIFO. I always look at 7 days in the future every night the perspective changes because tomorrow becomes today and day 7 can hold a new value.

What would be an efficient way to build something like this in postgres.
As it is now I would have to update all rows at night to move the values.
Is there a better way?

Comment: How do you measure something that doesn't exist yet?  Does the future day's value always show up atomically at the instant the renumbering occurs? Or do you have no #7 row if the new value is delayed beyond the cutoff for renumbering, and just end with start with #6?  Or does yesterday just stay at #1 until the new value shows up?

Comment: The data is based of a net requirement planning. the values from the next days are based of the values from the previous day and updated on events like a delivery.
#7 would be calculated based of the previous day when the "day switches".
I think of a cron that runs at midnight every day that moves the values an calculates the last one new.
It is more complex with more data, but for the sake of structure I simplified the example.

Comment: "Measure" was maybe the wrong word, I meant "calculate".

Comment: Why not store the actual date (according to the system clock) for Day.  Then you just delete any data from before the current day.  ?

Answer (score 1):

I would store `day` as a `DATE`. You can easily query the next seven days from that and generate the "day number" using a window function:

```
select id, row_number() over (order by day) as day_nr, value
from the_table
where day >= current_date 
  and day <= current_date + 7
```

To get rid of old rows, you simply run a DELETE statement with the necessary WHERE condition. To make that even more efficient, you can define the table with a range partition. Dropping a partition is a lot faster then running a DELETE on a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the table is into the millions of rows, you probably don't need to be too worried about efficiency.  My first impulse would be to just have a script every midnight that creates a new table from the old table with the needed updates, then drops the old table and renames the new one.  That won't play well with foreign keys, however.  (Actually, my first impulse would be question whether I really needed this volatile column in the first place--what do you do with this "day" column?  Is it only for presentation purposes or is it used in joins? And why do you have both a "day" and an "id" column which, in your example, get changed in lockstep and are always equal?)

The way version control works in PostgreSQL, it will be very hard to update an entire table with more efficiency than just recreating the table, even if only one column is being updated.

If you really need to minimize write churn, you could construct the "day" column on the fly from an absolute calendar date using the [row_number() windows function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).  And you could wrap this in a view so that it functions just like your existing table to the client.  However, that means you have extra overhead every time the view is accessed, so you trade one form of efficiency for another.